# i am getting error The 'make' utility is missing from PATH when i am building Docker file

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

when i build docker file i am getting error as '**The make' utility is missing from PATH**.

This is my Docker file

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine                                                          

WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                        
COPY ./requirements.txt /app                                                    

RUN apk --no-cache add shadow \                                                 
        gcc \                                                                       
        musl-dev \                                                                  
        postgresql-dev \                                                            
        python3-dev \                                                               
        freetype-dev \                                                              
        libffi-dev \                                                                
        tiff \                                                                      
        tiff-dev \                                                                  
        tk-dev \                                                                    
        tcl-dev \                                                                   
        postgresql \                                                                
        postgresql-dev \                                                            
        jpeg \                                                                      
        jpeg-dev \                                                                  
        zlib \                                                                      
        zlib-dev \                                                                  
        nodejs \                                                                    
        yarn \                                                                      
        && addgroup -g 1000 -S www-data \                                           
        && adduser -u 1000 -S -G www-data www-data \                                                               
        && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade 'pip<19.0' \                        
        && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \                         
        && apk del //\                                                                                             
            gcc \                                                                                                  
            musl-dev \                                                                                             
            tiff-dev \                                                                                             
            tcl-dev \                                                                                              
            jpeg-dev \                                                                                             
            zlib-dev \                                                                                             
            postgresql-dev \                                                                                       
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*                                                                                 

RUN chown www-data:www-data .                                                                                  USER www-data                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                   COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /app
```

---

---

```
 ./bin/build-and-run.sh 
    db uses an image, skipping
    rabbitmq uses an image, skipping
    elasticsearch uses an image, skipping
    Building backend
    Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.6-alpine
    3.6-alpine: Pulling from library/python
    Digest: sha256:4ae5142f052c4efd0bede8483f8ca43a73e8fcfce5dbf8f581967c2c9bac597b
    Status: Image is up to date for python:3.6-alpine
     ---> 1837080c5e87
    Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> a38347027d99
    Step 3/8 : COPY ./requirements.txt /app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 2aa3cf2383d1
    Step 4/8 : RUN apk --no-cache add shadow     gcc     musl-dev     postgresql-dev     python3-dev     freetype-dev     libffi-dev     tiff     tiff-dev     tk-dev     tcl-dev     postgresql     postgresql-dev     jpeg     jpeg-dev     zlib     zlib-dev     nodejs     yarn     && addgroup -g 1000 -S www-data     && adduser -u 1000 -S -G www-data www-data     && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade 'pip<19.0'     && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt     && apk del //        gcc         musl-dev         tiff-dev         tcl-dev         jpeg-dev         zlib-dev         postgresql-dev     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
     ---> Running in a4f145a67173
    fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
    fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
    (1/76) Installing libpng (1.6.34-r1)
    (2/76) Installing freetype (2.9.1-r1)
    (3/76) Installing pkgconf (1.5.3-r0)
    (4/76) Installing zlib-dev (1.2.11-r1)
    (5/76) Installing libpng-dev (1.6.34-r1)
    (6/76) Installing freetype-dev (2.9.1-r1)
    (7/76) Installing binutils (2.30-r5)
    (8/76) Installing gmp (6.1.2-r1)
    (9/76) Installing isl (0.18-r0)
    (10/76) Installing libgomp (6.4.0-r9)
    (11/76) Installing libatomic (6.4.0-r9)
    (12/76) Installing libgcc (6.4.0-r9)
    (13/76) Installing mpfr3 (3.1.5-r1)
    (14/76) Installing mpc1 (1.0.3-r1)
    (15/76) Installing libstdc++ (6.4.0-r9)
    (16/76) Installing gcc (6.4.0-r9)
    (17/76) Installing libjpeg-turbo (1.5.3-r4)
    (18/76) Installing libjpeg-turbo-utils (1.5.3-r4)
    (19/76) Installing jpeg (8-r6)
    (20/76) Installing libjpeg-turbo-dev (1.5.3-r4)
    (21/76) Installing jpeg-dev (8-r6)
    (22/76) Installing libffi-dev (3.2.1-r4)
    (23/76) Installing musl-dev (1.1.19-r10)
    (24/76) Installing c-ares (1.14.0-r0)
    (25/76) Installing libcrypto1.0 (1.0.2q-r0)
    (26/76) Installing http-parser (2.8.1-r0)
    (27/76) Installing libssl1.0 (1.0.2q-r0)
    (28/76) Installing libuv (1.20.2-r0)
    (29/76) Installing nodejs (8.14.0-r0)
    (30/76) Installing libedit (20170329.3.1-r3)
    (31/76) Installing db (5.3.28-r0)
    (32/76) Installing libsasl (2.1.26-r14)
    (33/76) Installing libldap (2.4.46-r0)
    (34/76) Installing libpq (10.5-r0)
    (35/76) Installing postgresql-client (10.5-r0)
    (36/76) Installing tzdata (2018f-r0)
    (37/76) Installing libxml2 (2.9.8-r1)
    (38/76) Installing postgresql (10.5-r0)
    (39/76) Installing libressl-dev (2.7.4-r0)
    (40/76) Installing postgresql-libs (10.5-r0)
    (41/76) Installing postgresql-dev (10.5-r0)
    (42/76) Installing python3 (3.6.6-r0)
    (43/76) Installing python3-dev (3.6.6-r0)
    (44/76) Installing linux-pam (1.3.0-r0)
    (45/76) Installing shadow (4.5-r0)
    (46/76) Installing tcl (8.6.7-r0)
    (47/76) Installing tcl-dev (8.6.7-r0)
    (48/76) Installing tiff (4.0.10-r0)
    (49/76) Installing tiff-dev (4.0.10-r0)
    (50/76) Installing libxau (1.0.8-r2)
    (51/76) Installing xproto (7.0.31-r1)
    (52/76) Installing libxau-dev (1.0.8-r2)
    (53/76) Installing xcb-proto (1.13-r2)
    (54/76) Installing libbsd (0.8.6-r2)
    (55/76) Installing libxdmcp (1.1.2-r4)
    (56/76) Installing libxcb (1.13-r2)
    (57/76) Installing libpthread-stubs (0.3-r5)
    (58/76) Installing libxdmcp-dev (1.1.2-r4)
    (59/76) Installing libxcb-dev (1.13-r2)
    (60/76) Installing xextproto (7.3.0-r2)
    (61/76) Installing xf86bigfontproto-dev (1.2.0-r5)
    (62/76) Installing xtrans (1.3.5-r1)
    (63/76) Installing inputproto (2.3.2-r1)
    (64/76) Installing libx11 (1.6.6-r0)
    (65/76) Installing kbproto (1.0.7-r2)
    (66/76) Installing libx11-dev (1.6.6-r0)
    (67/76) Installing libxrender (0.9.10-r2)
    (68/76) Installing fontconfig (2.12.6-r1)
    (69/76) Installing libxft (2.3.2-r2)
    (70/76) Installing expat-dev (2.2.5-r0)
    (71/76) Installing fontconfig-dev (2.12.6-r1)
    (72/76) Installing renderproto (0.11.1-r4)
    (73/76) Installing libxrender-dev (0.9.10-r2)
    (74/76) Installing libxft-dev (2.3.2-r2)
    (75/76) Installing tk-dev (8.6.6-r2)
    (76/76) Installing yarn (1.7.0-r0)
    Executing busybox-1.28.4-r2.trigger
    OK: 281 MiB in 109 packages
    Requirement already up-to-date: pip<19.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (18.1)
    You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    Collecting ansible==2.2.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/da/5e51cf931e4c7849ba698654877e2951ade8f842f28f0c904453a1d317d7/ansible-2.2.0.0.tar.gz (2.4MB)
    Collecting Django==2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/1a/e0ac7886c7123a03814178d7517dc822af0fe51a72e1a6bff26153103322/Django-2.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.3MB)
    Collecting django-storages==1.7.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/00/b15822dbc3ea8ea3b80dca394fafc758f5ced6bf4aa357f636f43e08de8d/django_storages-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44kB)
    https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/45/6b4bf4948608fcecb63e3f697903a7c1d9d74537d6b610c7ea2028cb1cfc/Collectfast-0.5.2-py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting django-extensions==2.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/37/669e64656240d1cbcf375731abc52440ff77ae7184f702aae031e381c8ea/autopep8-1.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
    Collecting sendgrid-django==4.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/d5/0efc17e01e9cf510b7efe5a80f8f977f5229f51e6c1ca813496871b2dc87/sendgrid-django-4.0.1.tar.gz
    Collecting Sphinx==1.6.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/96/97bebe9e13284fac32b6712ddf1dab5441f649ef24343ebfec98ba017553/Sphinx-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.9MB)
    Collecting sphinx-rtd-theme==0.2.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/50/849cd05961e7bafda2e0846ba80fa03f5a16a55fc5acc1d9f6bc79eb6fd9/sphinx_rtd_theme-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    Collecting pycrypto==2.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446kB)
    Collecting django-grappelli==2.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/51/f1506676a2bc4337a81114befdcedcc8b55946c9785e9e7e228141c75eea/django_grappelli-2.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.7MB)
    Collecting django-redis==4.8.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/98/f33d235cb0d6581137e618ec032daebffa65f8712930aae4158274d87b09/django_redis-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting redis==2.10.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
      https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/f6/7a76333cf0b9251ecf49efff635015171843d9b977e4ffcf59f9c4428052/redis-2.10.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64kB)
    Collecting paramiko (from ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
       https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/ae/94e70d49044ccc234bfdba20114fa947d7ba6eb68a2e452d89b920e62227/paramiko-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (193kB)

      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/a3/1d13970c3f36777c583f136c136f804d70f500168edc1edea6daa7200769/PyYAML-3.13.tar.gz (270kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (40.6.3)
    Collecting pytz (from Django==2.1->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
    Collecting six>=1.2.0 (from django-simple-captcha==0.5.9->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting Pillow!=5.1.0,>=2.2.2 (from django-simple-captcha==0.5.9->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/7e/443be24431324bd34d22dd9d11cc845d995bcd3b500676bcf23142756975/Pillow-5.4.1.tar.gz (16.0MB)
    Collecting django-ranged-response==0.2.0 (from django-simple-captcha==0.5.9->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/e3/9372fcdca8e9c3205e7979528ccd1a14354a9a24d38efff11c1846ff8bf1/django-ranged-response-0.2.0.tar.gz
    Collecting rjsmin==1.0.12 (from django-compressor==2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 10))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/9c/2c45f57d43258b05bf33cf8f6c8161ea5abf8b4776a5c59d12646727cd98/rjsmin-1.0.12.tar.gz (446kB)
    Collecting rcssmin==1.0.6 (from django-compressor==2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 10))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/5f/852be8aa80d1c24de9b030cdb6532bc7e7a1c8461554f6edbe14335ba890/rcssmin-1.0.6.tar.gz (582kB)
    Collecting django-appconf>=1.0 (from django-compressor==2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 10))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/78/726cdf3e04660560cf25f9def95b8f2736310c581dabed9adfe60154a9f8/django_appconf-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting amqp>=1.4.6 (from librabbitmq==2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 14))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/c3/a3b303cab73a9c3ee699f7229b33e262536204cfa9fe5df5274b1cf3dd4e/amqp-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49kB)
    Collecting billiard<3.6.0,>=3.5.0.2 (from celery==4.2.1->-r requirements.txt (line 15))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/b7/c2fe04f2522bb02d044347734eeda3ff5c7a632fa7d0401530a371ba73db/billiard-3.5.0.5.tar.gz (150kB)
    Collecting kombu<5.0,>=4.2.0 (from celery==4.2.1->-r requirements.txt (line 15))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/5d/a4162de3033be4b42e59ee5101de92b218a6b0a943de9cbe8bab5c45479a/kombu-4.2.2.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (177kB)
    Collecting nose>=1.2.1 (from django-nose==1.4.4->-r requirements.txt (line 16))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/d8/dd071918c040f50fa1cf80da16423af51ff8ce4a0f2399b7bf8de45ac3d9/nose-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl (154kB)
    Collecting sendgrid<4,>=3.5 (from sendgrid-django==4.0.1->-r requirements.txt (line 20))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/be/5c2cf158c9036224676b3b01042c27d722fba63b46cb87a4fdaf24fa3621/sendgrid-3.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting babel!=2.0,>=1.3 (from Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/ad/c6f60602d3ee3d92fbed87675b6fb6a6f9a38c223343ababdb44ba201f10/Babel-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.1MB)
    Collecting sphinxcontrib-websupport (from Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/69/3c2fbdc3702358c5b34ee25e387b24838597ef099761fc9a42c166796e8f/sphinxcontrib_websupport-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting Pygments>=2.0 (from Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/e5/6d710c9cf96c31ac82657bcfb441df328b22df8564d58d0c4cd62612674c/Pygments-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (849kB)
    Collecting requests>=2.0.0 (from Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/e3/20f3d364d6c8e5d2353c72a67778eb189176f08e873c9900e10c0287b84b/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
    Collecting alabaster<0.8,>=0.7 (from Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/ad/00b090d23a222943eb0eda509720a404f531a439e803f6538f35136cae9e/alabaster-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting docutils>=0.11 (from Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/fa/08e9e6e0e3cbd1d362c3bbee8d01d0aedb2155c4ac112b19ef3cae8eed8d/docutils-0.14-py3-none-any.whl (543kB)
    Collecting snowballstemmer>=1.1 (from Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/6c/8a935e2c7b54a37714656d753e4187ee0631988184ed50c0cf6476858566/snowballstemmer-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64kB)
    Collecting imagesize (from Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/b6/aef66b4c52a6ad6ac18cf6ebc5731ed06d8c9ae4d3b2d9951f261150be67/imagesize-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko->ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/ab/2ac6dea8489fa713e2b4c6c5b549cc962dd4a842b5998d9e80cf8440b7cd/PyNaCl-1.3.0.tar.gz (3.4MB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko->ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/7c/c9386b82a25115cccf1903441bba3cbadcfae7b678a20167347fa8ded34c/pyasn1-0.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (73kB)
    Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3 (from paramiko->ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/3a/3d540b9f5ee8d92ce757eebacf167b9deedb8e30aedec69a2a072b2399bb/bcrypt-3.1.6.tar.gz (42kB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Collecting cryptography>=1.5 (from paramiko->ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/ed/5e97b7f54237a9e4e6291b6e52173372b7fa45ca730d36ea90b790c0059a/cryptography-2.5.tar.gz (487kB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2->ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/7e/1b4c2e05809a4414ebce0892fe1e32c14ace86ca7d50c70f00979ca9b3a3/MarkupSafe-1.1.0.tar.gz
    Collecting vine>=1.1.3 (from amqp>=1.4.6->librabbitmq==2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 14))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/dd/e30f828a39914626d67876b987d6fc47616b64de680cd0f746fc9c8aab47/vine-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting python-http-client>=2.1.1 (from sendgrid<4,>=3.5->sendgrid-django==4.0.1->-r requirements.txt (line 20))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/74/e43e494a44e78a1188552aa9dfc2f738cd4089b6f8a18c49f186f2b841a3/python_http_client-3.1.0.tar.gz
    Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.0.0->Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.0.0->Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.0.0->Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/e0/accfc1b56b57e9750eba272e24c4dddeac86852c2bebd1236674d7887e8a/certifi-2018.11.29-py2.py3-none-any.whl (154kB)
    Collecting urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.0.0->Sphinx==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 21))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/00/ee1d7de624db8ba7090d1226aebefab96a2c71cd5cfa7629d6ad3f61b79e/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118kB)
    Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko->ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/a7/4cd50e57cc6f436f1cc3a7e8fa700ff9b8b4d471620629074913e3735fb2/cffi-1.11.5.tar.gz (438kB)
    Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko->ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (101kB)
    Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko->ansible==2.2.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/9e/49196946aee219aead1290e00d1e7fdeab8567783e83e1b9ab5585e6206a/pycparser-2.19.tar.gz (158kB)
    Installing collected packages: six, pycparser, cffi, pynacl, pyasn1, bcrypt, asn1crypto, cryptography, paramiko, MarkupSafe, jinja2, PyYAML, pycrypto, ansible, pytz, Django, django-storages, psycopg2, django-settings-export, django-filter, django-bootstrap4, Pillow, django-ranged-response, django-simple-captcha, django-tinymce, rjsmin, rcssmin, django-appconf, django-compressor, csscompressor, Collectfast, django-extensions, vine, amqp, librabbitmq, billiard, kombu, celery, nose, django-nose, model-mommy, pep8, autopep8, python-http-client, sendgrid, sendgrid-django, babel, sphinxcontrib-websupport, Pygments, idna, chardet, certifi, urllib3, requests, alabaster, docutils, snowballstemmer, imagesize, Sphinx, sphinx-rtd-theme, django-grappelli, redis, django-redis
      Running setup.py install for pycparser: started
        Running setup.py install for pycparser: finished with status 'done'
      Running setup.py install for cffi: started
        Running setup.py install for cffi: finished with status 'done'
      Running setup.py install for pynacl: started
        Running setup.py install for pynacl: finished with status 'error'
        Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-b134a65q/pynacl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-_zdi99rl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/secret.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/public.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/encoding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/hash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/hashlib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        copying src/nacl/signing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/pwhash
        copying src/nacl/pwhash/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/pwhash
        copying src/nacl/pwhash/_argon2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/pwhash
        copying src/nacl/pwhash/argon2id.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/pwhash
        copying src/nacl/pwhash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/pwhash
        copying src/nacl/pwhash/argon2i.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/pwhash
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_secretbox.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_box.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_secretstream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_shorthash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/sodium_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_scalarmult.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_aead.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_kx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/randombytes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_sign.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_generichash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_hash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_pwhash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/nacl/bindings
        running build_clib
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-install-b134a65q/pynacl/setup.py", line 255, in <module>
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uogfsb2e/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 143, in setup
            return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uogfsb2e/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
            return orig.install.run(self)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
            self.run_command('build')
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
            self.run_command(cmd_name)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/tmp/pip-install-b134a65q/pynacl/setup.py", line 159, in run
            raise Exception("ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH")
        Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-b134a65q/pynacl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-_zdi99rl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-b134a65q/pynacl/
    You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: add `build-essential` package at the top of your list of apk packages (and you could then remove `gcc`, which is a dependency of build-essential)

Answer (score 10):

`make` isn't installed. Just add it to the end of your apk list

```
nodejs \
yarn \
make
```

and it should work.

I can't test, I'm afraid, since I don't know what your requirements are, and can't, off the top of my head, think of a python package that requires making!

Additionally, I'm not sure you're using apk del correctly - you have:

```
apk del //\
```

which I think is a syntax error. I'm fairly sure you're just after

```
apk del \
```

on that line.